# How to delete Stream Depot in perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec, perforce-branch-spec

I use P4Admin to create Stream Depot (named **streamDepot**) in perforce, then I create a Stream(main) by client, I populated it with client workspace and with a project. But when I try to obliterate the files and delete that **streamDepot** depot with P4Admin, I got no luck. Message says:

```
Depot 'streamDepot' is the location of existing streams; cannot delete until they are removed.
```

So what is the meaning of existing streams? I already deleted client namespace and files which mapped to **streamDepot**'s Stream(main). What should I do? I dont see any files in **streamDepot** (no main stream or stream types) with viewing P4Admin by Depots Tab.

Comment: The stream is a separate concept from the files in the stream. Just as you created the stream and then populated it with files, you have to obliterate the files, then delete the stream. But why do you need to delete the stream depot? Is it causing you problems? Generally, depots are created and never deleted.

Comment: I obliterate files already but no luck when deleting.

Comment: You can run 'p4 streams' to view the streams in your stream depot, and 'p4 stream -d' to delete an unused stream.

Comment: oh thanks p4 stream -d //streamDepot/Main then its ok now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the `Streamdepot` you created a `main` stream along with it (I believe, its been a while since we set ours up.)  I would hazard a guess you just need to delete that stream and then you should be good to delete the depot.  look for `//streamdepot/Main` obliterate the files, obliterate the stream, obliterate the depot.

Comment: I use  p4 stream -d //streamDepot/Main and its ok now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Initially none of the above solutions worked because when I created the stream, I didn't notice the checkbox that said **Create a workspace to use with this steam** as shown below:

[image]

Naturally this lead to the same error as reported by the OP when I tried to delete the streams and depot later:

> Depot 'xxx' is the location of existing streams; cannot delete until they are removed.

Eventually I realised the cause (the workspace) and deleted the offending workspace(s) from the **Workspaces** tab:

[image]

With the workspaces deleted, I was able to delete the stream(s) and depot from the **Streams** tab and **P4Admin** respectively.  No need for command-line.